# Xpath result Placing colon instead of dash

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse the following XML using XPath for some reason it places colons instead of dashes, i do not have control over the source feed and would like to get the original URL.

here is the xml :

```
<entry>
   <link href="http://www.iol.co.za/polopoly_fs/iol-news-oct29-sa-justice-read-only-1.1736573!/image/2509245336.jpg_gen/derivatives/box_501/2509245336.jpg" rel="enclosure" type="image/jpg"/>
</entry>
```

here is the XPath Expression:

```
/entry/link[@rel="enclosure"]/@href
```

The result is

> href="http://www.iol.co.za/polopoly_fs/iol:news:oct29:sa:justice:read:only:1.1736573!/image/2509245336.jpg_gen/derivatives/box_501/2509245336.jpg"

where i am expecting : http://www.iol.co.za/polopoly_fs/iol-news-oct29-sa-justice-read-only-1.1736573!/image/2509245336.jpg_gen/derivatives/box_501/2509245336.jpg

The Query is for some reason replacing all the "-" chars with ":"

What am I doing wrong ?

Screen shot from http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester

[image: Screenshot from http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester]

Comment: Curious. How are you running your xpath? What processor? What programming language?

Comment: i actually am using it in drupal as part of feed import, but i am getting this result using http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester too

Comment: This XPath gets rid of the "href" `string(/entry/link[@rel="enclosure"]/@href)`. But the xpath processor you are using may be bugged though, because the result of this xpath replaces all colons ":" with dashes "-" (opposite of your original issue). Using other processors gives the correct result though (e.g. http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output)

Comment: Thank you. I think the xpath testing tool was the culprit, after, testing / debugging in php the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath is fine, but it seems that the site is doing some strange things do the input.

Look at http://codebeautify.org/js/viewer/allviewer.js, line 1607, where the XML input is stored in variable x, and all `:` are replaced to `-` before the XPath expression is evaluated:

```
var x = $("#xmlString").val();
var pattrn = /:/g;
var pattrn1 = /-/g;

x = x.replace(pattrn, '-');
var xml = $.parseXML(x);
```

Later in the XPath result the reverse is done (e.g. line 1661, 1667).

But the side-effect is that if your input contains `-` characters they are all converted to `:`.

You may want to contact the site author and inform about this.

Comment: Thanks I won't be using that site anymore.